# Get values from a smaller DataFrame with a specified step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposing I have the two `DataFrames` shown below:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame([1,0, 3, 0, 5])

   0
0  1
1  0
2  3
3  0
4  5
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,4])

   0
0  2
1  4
```

How can I broadcast the values of `df` into `dd` with *step = 2* so I end up with

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd.values[1::2] = df.values`

`dd` now contains:

```
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

Note that here `step=2` condition is used. array[1::2] syntax means start from the array element with index 1, until the end, with step=2.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame([1, 0, 3, 0, 5])                                                                               
df = pd.DataFrame([2, 4])                                                                                       
dd.iloc[1::2] = df.values 
dd
# Out:
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `df.index` by range and fill second `DataFrame`:

```
df.index = range(1, len(dd)+1, 2)[:len(df)]
print (df)
   0
1  2
3  4

dd.loc[df.index] = df
print (dd)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```